# User Check-in base on proximity

Tags: android, ios, ibeacon, proximity

We were thinking of an automated user check-in for a loyalty program base on beacon proximity. Even though we feel this creates a friction-less user experience (without needing to identify yourself with a card or phone number or name), but we are very concerned of user adoption as research showed there are only 33% of the smartphone users turning on their bluetooth.

My questions:

1. Is there a way for mobile app (iOS and Android) to still read the beacon broadcast in the background even though Bluetooth is off ?
2. Is there any other alternative solution other than using beacon proximity to achieve this user experience? NFC or QR code requires user action which we try to avoid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot detect bluetooth beacons if bluetooth is turned off.  However, you can detect that bluetooth is off and prompt the user to turn it on.

Comment: We saw PayPal is doing this as well with beacon check-in with their PayPal Beacon. As I am not in US, do you see PayPal method is gaining acceptance as it does required users to have their BT on. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7kJ1LOHJ5g  Thanks!

Comment: To add to what David said, you can try to convince the users of your app to turn Bluetooth on during the app onboarding. Just like proper onboarding increases the chance the user will allow push notifications or access to location services, if you explain the value and let people know battery impact is minimal (many still remember the days of the early, less energy-efficient BT), you might convince them to turn and keep BT on.

Comment: I think users will increasingly leave Bluetooth on.  Apple, for example, automatically turns Bluetooth on when users upgrade iOS.